# Google News API, paid verision

Tags: google-api, bing-api, google-news

Does Google offer any sort of API etc for Google News. Either for free or paid. I know that the previous version was deprecated. It should be used for commercial use so I guess I can not use their RSS feeds.

I know that Bing offer paid API, but they have far less news sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google and Yahoo doesn't offer the search APIs anymore. Bing is your choice if you're considering the 3 search giants. You can also take a look at [news aggregators with APIs](http://www.programmableweb.com/category/News%20Services/apis?category=20250). If you can't find one API that suits the number of sources you need, then use more APIs. That should increase your coverage.

Comment: Ok, however I am chasing Swedish news in particular. So Google News was my top choice. Thanks though.